# JQuery  Stop() function don't stop animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have 2 sentences and `highlight` each word with an `animation`.

if i press `"First Line"` button animation will play for first line and if press `"Sec Line"` button first line animation will stop and sec line animation will play.

**JQuery Code**

```
var time = 15; 

$("#go").click(function(){
  $("abbr", "#2" ).stop(true,true); 
    $("abbr", "#1").each(function(i,e) {
           $(e).delay(i * ((time * 1000) / $("abbr",  "#1").length))
               .animate({'color': 'red'}, 1, function () {
               $(e).animate({ 'color': 'black' }, 5000);
               });
    });
});

$("#back").click(function(){
    $("abbr", "#1" ).stop(true,true);
    $("abbr", "#2").each(function(i,e) {
           $(e).delay(i * ((time * 1000) / $("abbr",  "#2").length))
               .animate({'color': 'red'}, 1, function () {
               $(e).animate({ 'color': 'black' }, 5000);
               });
    }); });
```

**Html Code**

```
<span id="1">
    <abbr>fractal </abbr>
    <abbr>is a mathematical </abbr>
    <abbr>that has </abbr> 
    <abbr>a fractal dimension </abbr> 
    <abbr>that usually</abbr> 
    <abbr>exceeds its </abbr> 
    <abbr>topological dimension</abbr> 
    <abbr>fractal </abbr>
    <abbr>is a mathematical </abbr>
    <abbr>that has </abbr> 
    <abbr>a fractal dimension </abbr> 
    <abbr>that usually</abbr> 
    <abbr>exceeds its </abbr> 
    <abbr>topological dimension</abbr>  
</span>
<br>
 <br> 
 <span id="2">
    <abbr>and may </abbr>
    <abbr>fall between </abbr>
    <abbr>the integers </abbr> 
    <abbr>Fractals </abbr> 
    <abbr>are typically </abbr> 
    <abbr>self-similar </abbr> 
    <abbr>patterns</abbr> 
    <abbr>and may </abbr>
    <abbr>fall between </abbr>
    <abbr>the integers </abbr> 
    <abbr>Fractals </abbr> 
    <abbr>are typically </abbr> 
    <abbr>self-similar </abbr> 
    <abbr>patterns</abbr>  
</span> 
<br>
 <br> 
<button id="go">First Line</button> 
<button id="back">Sec Line</button>
```

every thing is fine,but when i play first line animation and after some sec for example(`3 sec`)
press `"sec line"` button animation and again after(for example 3 sec) press first line animation animation will start from begin and from middle of sentence.

Result: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5VTg/1/)**

[image]

i think `stop()` function have some problem.
please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution

instead of using

```
 $("abbr", "#2" ).stop(true,true); 
 $("abbr", "#1" ).stop(true,true);
```

i use

```
  $("abbr").stop(false,true);
```

result:
http://jsfiddle.net/d5VTg/3/

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you can clear your delay-queue. Try using a timer inside the loop instead:

```
// check if the timer is running, in that case, clear it: clearTimeout(timer);

var timer = setTimeout(function(){

    //do animation stuff

}, (i * ((time * 1000) / $("abbr",  "#1").length)));
```